# grunt isn’t working anymore, might be because of gem path

Tags: ruby, macos, gruntjs, npm, rubygems

So Grunt used to work fine on my Mac OSX El Capitan. A few days ago, I installed Jekyll and then when I went back to another project that already used Grunt, and it suddenly gives these errors.

```
Haneens-MacBook-Pro:hk-2015-v2 HRK$ grunt
/Users/HRK/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'grunt' (>= 0) among 24 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/HRK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/Users/HRK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/HRK/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/HRK/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /Users/HRK/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/grunt:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/HRK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/HRK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I tried to edit the path for npm to be `usr/local/bin`
So I edited the etc/paths file to have the following

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

How can I solve this problem? I’m a beginner and it’s extremely frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

First try:

```
gem list
```

to see if you have `grunt` installed.

Then you can trouble shoot by:

```
gem env
```

Looking for `GEM PATHS`, to see if it's the path where your gem installed.

Then your can use

```
export GEM_PATH=/path/to/your/gem/dir
```

to add the correct path.